# How many integers from $1000$ and $9999$ have the same digit exactly thrice?

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:**

> How many integers from $1000$ and $9999$ have the same digit exactly thrice?

**Approach** $\bf 1$**:**

> For $abbb$ we have $9\cdot9$ ways.
> For $babb$ we have $10\cdot8$ ways.
> So, total number of integers required $=9\cdot9+10\cdot8\times3=321$

**Approach** $\bf 2$**:**

> For $abbb$ we have $9\cdot9$ ways.
> For $abaa$ we have $9\cdot9$ ways.
> So, total number of integers required $=9\cdot9+9\cdot9\times3=324$

Between $a$ and $b$, I'm first selecting $a$, which is causing the difference.

Why Approach $1$ is wrong while $2$ correct? 
How to know when I'm making/committing folly?

Comment: In approach $\#1$:  Why does $babb$ yield $10\times 8$?  There are $9$ choices for $b$ and then another $9$ for $a$.

Comment: @lulu That's approach 2.

Comment: @lulu because $1$st I'm looking at $a$ for which there are $10$ choices and then I'm left with $8$ choices for $b$.

Comment: @Arthur  I understand that, but I can't see the logic behind $10\times 8$.  Sure, you have $10$ choices for $a$, but then you have to distinguish between $a=0$ and $a>0$.

Comment: @InanimateBeing  No...if you choose $a=0$ you have $9$ choices for $b$.

Comment: @lulu Which is the answer to the question being asked: "Where does approach 1 go wrong?"

Comment: @lulu thank you, I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than you selecting fist $a$, you should treat case $a$ = 0 specifically.
$a = 0$ $b$ can be [1, 9], so $1\cdot9$
$a \neq 0$ $b$ can be [1, 9], but not $a$ so $9\cdot8$
$$1\cdot9+9\cdot8=9\cdot9$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. +1.

Answer (score 2):

In approach 1 case 2, if you happen to pick $a = 0$, you have 9 options for $b$, not $8$. This accounts for the additional 3 possibilities that approach 2 picks up (one for each position for $a$).

Comment: Thank you. Got it. +1.